# Create list of object in python

Tags: python, list, class

I have to create a list of Student which contain name and roll number of student
but when i am creating new object of class student ad appending it to my list every object in list are changed and getting same data for all student 
what should i do?? 
Code:

```
class Student:
    name = 'abc'
    roll_no = 1

    def print_info (self):
        print(Student.name,"\t",Student.roll_no)

    def input_info (self):
        Student.roll_no = int(input("Enter Student roll number  "))
        Student.name = input("Enter Student name  ")

ch=1
students = []

while ch!=3:
    print("1.Create new Student\n2. Display students\n3.Exit")
    ch=int(input("Enter choice\t"))`enter code here`
    if ch==1 :
        tmp=Student()
        tmp.input_info()
        students.append(tmp)
    elif ch==2:
        print("---Students Details---")
        print("Name\tRoll No")
    for i in students:
        i.print_info()
```

Output:
[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NeDM.png)

Comment: creating object of student

Comment: `Student.roll_no = ` and `Student.name = ` are not doing what you think they do.

Comment: @DeepSpace so how to print those values

Comment: Please read the duplicated question and understand the difference between class attributes and instance attributes

Comment: You'll need to use a `__init__` method for that, and initialize the variables there.

Comment: @DeepSpace i am getting problem when i am append it to list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for the append method is as follow:

```
list.append(obj)
```

So you should replace `students.append()` by:

```
students.append(tmp)
```

Moreover, your `print_info` and `input_info` methods are not displaying the properties of a given student, but the properties of the class `Student` itself (which are always the same for every instance of the class). You should fix that.

Comment: done! but still same problem

Comment: Yeah there are some more issues, I was a bit quick to answer. I'll try to edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: how to  do that??